# Set column width based on number of modules in position

Tags: php, module, module-display, bootstrap

I have 4 module positions, which based on the number of modules I'd like to resize the column width.  I've written the following, but it's only setting them all to col-md-12. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
<?php 

if($this->countModules('bottom-a'))
    {
        $bottom-col-width == "col-md-12";
    }
    elseif($this->countModules('bottom-a') && $this->countModules('bottom-b'))
        {
            $bottom-col-width == "col-md-6";
        }
    elseif($this->countModules('bottom-a') && $this->countModules('bottom-b') && $this->countModules('bottom-c'))
        {
            $bottom-col-width == "col-md-4";
        }
    elseif($this->countModules('bottom-a') && $this->countModules('bottom-b') && $this->countModules('bottom-c') && $this->countModules('bottom-d'))
        {
            $bottom-col-width == "col-md-3";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Read your code precisely. if bottom-a then width is col-md-12 elseif....
When module bottom-a exists, the elseif will not even be checked. Your first condition is true, so the if-clause ends here... so the next elseif's are ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These `if` statements wont work. Imagine if there is module in positions `bottom-b` and `bottom-c`. Even if you would reverse `if` statements, none of those wont match.

To achieve what you want, `if` statements would be too complicated.

Rather do it like this:

```
<?php

// Default width - for one column
// This gets new value, if there is more than one active position
$bottomColWidth = "col-md-12";

// Number of positions, which have modules
$countOfActivePositions = 0;

// Positions to search modules in
$positions = array('bottom-a', 'bottom-b', 'bottom-c', 'bottom-d');

// Loop over every position
foreach ($positions as $position) {
  // If position has modules
  if($this->countModules($position)){
    // Increase active positions count
    $countOfActivePositions++;
  }
}

if($countOfActivePositions > 1){
  $bottomColWidth = "col-md-".(12 / $countOfActivePositions);
}

?>
```

This would work in every combination possible.